# Pyomo: ERROR: evaluating expression: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object

Tags: pyomo

I am working on an Pyomo optimization script.  It is moderately complex with indexed parameters and variables and 8 constraints.  If I leave the decision variables with no initial value, I get "ERROR: evaluating expression: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object" errors for constraints involving a decision variable.  If I initialize the decision variables to 1 or 0 the solver(glpk) returns Status: optimal and objective function value = 0. All decision variables are also set to 0. I am looking for ideas about how to troubleshoot this.  Below is relevant code (w/o data) and the output from the solver and model.display, which has been edited to make it more compact.

```
#Sets
#clinics
model.C = Set(initialize=list(clinics.keys()))

#clients
model.B = Set(initialize=list(client_blocks.keys()))

#scalar params
model.clt_stf_max = 10
model.tt_max = 45
model.selected_clinic_max = 4
model.stf_max = sum(staff_cap.values())  #total available staff is sum of clinic new staff capacity
model.z_M = 5000  #used in clients at selected clinics constraint
model.e_M = 500   #used in staff at selected clinics constraint

#indexed params
model.cnc_stf_cap = Param(C, initialize=staff_cap)
model.clt_blk = Param(B, initialize=client_blocks)
model.trav_time = Param(T, initialize=trav_time)

#decision vars
#x new staff at each clinic
model.new_stf = Var(model.C, domain=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=0) 

#y new clients at each clinic/block combo  
model.new_clt = Var(model.C, model.B, domain=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=0) 

#z client at selected clinics only 
model.z =  Var(model.C, model.B, domain=Binary, initialize=0)

#e staff at selected clinics only 
model.e = Var(model.C, domain=Binary, initialize=0) 

#objective function
def o_min_tt_rule(model):
    return sum(model.trav_time[c,b]*model.new_clt[c,b] for c in model.C for b in model.B)
model.o_min_tt = Objective(rule=o_min_tt_rule, sense=minimize)

#constraints
# limit new clients at clinic to staff capacity  
def limit_clients_to_clinic_staff_cap_rule(model, c):
    return sum(model.new_clt[c,b] for c in model.C for b in model.B) <= (model.cnc_stf_cap[c] * model.clt_stf_max)
model.limit_clients_to_clinic_staff_cap = Constraint(model.C, rule=limit_clients_to_clinic_staff_cap_rule)

#total of new clients served in block should not exceed the number new clients in the block 
def limit_newclient_block_rule(model, b):
    return sum(model.new_clt[c,b] for c in model.C for b in model.B) <= (model.clt_blk[b])
model.limit_newclient_block = Constraint(model.B, rule=limit_newclient_block_rule)

#limit new clients to selected clinics
def client_to_selected_clinic_rule(model, c, b):
   return model.new_clt[c,b] <= model.z[c,b] * model.z_M
model.client_to_selected_clinic = Constraint(model.C, model.B, rule=client_to_selected_clinic_rule)

#limit single client travel time to max travel time minutes
def limit_client_travtime_rule(model, c, b):
    return (model.trav_time[c,b] * model.z[c,b]) <= model.tt_max
model.limit_client_travtime = Constraint(model.C, model.B, rule=limit_client_travtime_rule)

#limit selected clinics to max number
def limit_selected_clinic_to_max_rule(model):
    return summation(model.e) <= model.selected_clinic_max
model.limit_selected_clinic_to_max = Constraint(rule=limit_selected_clinic_to_max_rule,)

#limit new staff to selected clinics
def staff_to_selected_clinic_rule(model, c):
    return model.new_stf[c] <= model.e[c] * model.e_M
model.staff_to_selected_clinic = Constraint(model.C, rule=staff_to_selected_clinic_rule)

#limit new staff at clinic to clinic capacity
def limit_staff_to_clnic_cap_rule(model, c):
    return model.new_stf[c] <= model.cnc_stf_cap[c]
model.limit_staff_to_clnic_cap = Constraint(model.C, rule=limit_staff_to_clnic_cap_rule)

#limit total new staff to staff max   
def limit_tot_staff_rule(model):
    return summation(model.new_stf) <= model.stf_max
model.limit_tot_staff = Constraint(rule=limit_tot_staff_rule)


# solve the model 
solver = SolverFactory("glpk", tee=True, warmstart=True, symbolic_solver_labels=True)
```

OUTPUT from solver and model.display()

```
SOLVER:
Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 0.0
  Upper bound: 0.0
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 753
  Number of variables: 665
  Number of nonzeros: 29213
  Sense: minimize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Termination condition: optimal
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 1
      Number of created subproblems: 1
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.10507559776306152
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 1
  number of solutions displayed: 1
- Gap: 0.0
  Status: optimal
  Message: None
  Objective:
    o_min_tt:
      Value: 0
  Variable: No nonzero values
  Constraint: No values
```

MODEL:

```
Model (Staff_Allocation)

  Variables:
    new_stf : Size=4, Index=Clinics
        Key                                       : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                 FEDCAP Counseling Center - 01004 :     0 :     0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
        The Salvation Army Belmont Center - 04002 :     0 :     0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
                      VIP Wellness Center - 12000 :     0 :     0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
         Westchester Center of Excellence - 11006 :     0 :     0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers
    new_clt : Size=392, Index=new_clt_index
        Key                                                            : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                 ('FEDCAP Counseling Center - 01004', 360050019001022) :     0 :     0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeIntegers

    z : Size=392, Index=z_index
        Key                                                            : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                 ('FEDCAP Counseling Center - 01004', 360050019001022) :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    e : Size=4, Index=Clinics
        Key                                       : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
                 FEDCAP Counseling Center - 01004 :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
        The Salvation Army Belmont Center - 04002 :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
                      VIP Wellness Center - 12000 :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
         Westchester Center of Excellence - 11006 :     0 :     0 :     1 : False : False : Binary

  Objectives:
    o_min_tt : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Value
        None :   True :     0

  Constraints:
    limit_clients_to_clinic_staff_cap : Size=4
        Key                                       : Lower : Body : Upper
                 FEDCAP Counseling Center - 01004 :  None :    0 : 200.0
        The Salvation Army Belmont Center - 04002 :  None :    0 : 150.0
                      VIP Wellness Center - 12000 :  None :    0 : 150.0
         Westchester Center of Excellence - 11006 :  None :    0 : 250.0

    limit_newclient_block : Size=98
        Key             : Lower : Body : Upper
        360050019001022 :  None :    0 :   1.0
        .... 97 more like this

    client_to_selected_clinic : Size=392
        Key                                                            : Lower : Body : Upper
                 ('FEDCAP Counseling Center - 01004', 360050019001022) :  None :    0 :   0.0
        .... 391 more like this

    limit_client_travtime : Size=392
        Key                                                            : Lower : Body : Upper
                 ('FEDCAP Counseling Center - 01004', 360050019001022) :  None :    0 :  75.0
        .... 391 more like this

    limit_selected_clinic_to_max : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :  None :    0 :   4.0

    staff_to_selected_clinic : Size=4
        Key                                       : Lower : Body : Upper
                 FEDCAP Counseling Center - 01004 :  None :    0 :   0.0
        The Salvation Army Belmont Center - 04002 :  None :    0 :   0.0
                      VIP Wellness Center - 12000 :  None :    0 :   0.0
         Westchester Center of Excellence - 11006 :  None :    0 :   0.0

    limit_staff_to_clnic_cap : Size=4
        Key                                       : Lower : Body : Upper
                 FEDCAP Counseling Center - 01004 :  None :    0 :   4.0
        The Salvation Army Belmont Center - 04002 :  None :    0 :   3.0
                      VIP Wellness Center - 12000 :  None :    0 :   3.0
         Westchester Center of Excellence - 11006 :  None :    0 :   5.0

    limit_tot_staff : Size=1
        Key  : Lower : Body : Upper
        None :  None :    0 :  15.0
```

Comment: Do you get the `ERROR: evaluating expression` message when you try to `display()` or `pprint()` the model?

Comment: I do not get the same error during display() output.  Instead I get TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting when trying to write display() to a file.  The error occurs as it is starting to write the results of one of the constraints.